# Using Phonegap for bb10, touch, and non-touch devices

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10

I intend to develop a Blackberry app targeting the older devices and new BB 10. Is it that I have to develop different apps for older platform, new BB10 platform, for touch, and for non-touch devices? Please also guide me on how I can publish this as a single app. Any other info related to this subject would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically you could do a single app: BB10 devices, even the ones with HW keyboard, are all touch-enabled. For BB7 you should make sure to strategically make some fields cursor-focus friendly, but the main issue would be the poor browser performance.

Answer (score 0):

read for [phonegap](http://techbirds.in/?p=500) and [webworks](http://techbirds.in/?p=495). You can do this with single app code just keep in mind

1. change the config file when switching from BBOS 7 and lower to BB 10.
2. In BBOS 7 remove one line from your config.xml that says something like focus-enable then default focus control would be cursor oriented.